How do I use picocom to download a file from an embedded Linux device to my local machine?
I am using macOS, and I have installed sz, rz, and picocom, and I can connect to the serial device normally, for example,
picocom -b 1500000 /dev/tty.wchusbserial141100.

But how can I download a specific file from the device?

Does the device itself have any file transfer software installed? Things like sz or kermit? Does the embedded device not have a network connection? That would be simpler.

This embedded device does not have Ethernet and can only communicate via USB serial communication by sz rz, it's installed in device.

On my system, I have rz and sz installed on the host PC, and lrz and lsz installed on the target device. To send a file from the device to the host using ZMODEM, I run lsz filename on the device, then type Ctrl-A Ctrl-R on the host. At the *** file:  prompt, do not type a filename (because it is not used by ZMODEM), just press Enter. To send a file from the PC to the device using ZMODEM, I run lrz on the device, then type Ctrl-A Ctrl-S on the host. At the *** file:  prompt, type the name of the file to be sent.

@IanAbbott, When your receive file on the host, the filename prompt is for the Picocom to name your file accordingly. When you left it blank, what is the default filename in your case? (I am always typing the filename, so I know exactly what it will be on the receiver side)

@Ian Abbott Your solution helped me solve the problem. Thank you very much.

@0andriy The filename entered in picocom's *** file:  prompt is added as a command line parameter for the send or receive program running on the host. At least for the rz command installed by Debian's lrzsz package, that causes rz to exit with an error. It will use the filename sent by by the sending side of the ZMODEM protocol.

@IanAbbott, okay, I think I have custom rs/sz parameters passed to picocom, that’s why it works for me, but I will be able to check this within a couple of weeks, after my vacation.
